# Error with Virto Commerce Smart Caching Module after fresh install from source code

Tags: virtocommerce

After doing a fresh install of the VC platform and VC storefront from source code, I chose to install the sample data. I am getting an error in the Smart Caching Module, which states `Module platform version 2.13.28 is incompatible with current 2.13.26;`

In my VC Platform solution, I can see the version is in fact set to `2.13.26` in my common assembly file - and in my Smart Caching Module the target version is in fact set to `2.13.28`.

How can I roll back the Smart Caching Module to target the `2.13.26` version? Or is it easier to upgrade the platform to version `2.13.28`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the easiest way to update your VC platform to the latest version. https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-platform/releases